# Issues with bitmap character spacing

Tags: c#, graphics, text

I've been working on a bitmap character renderer for my game engine in C#, however, I've been running into some spacing-related problems.

This script parses the font and gets all the relevant data from the bitmap file. The bitmap file uses the Angel Code format, with characters defined like this:

> char id=35      x=357  y=327  width=51   height=57   xoffset=-7   yoffset=15   xadvance=53

Where `id` is the Unicode value, `x`, `y`, `width`, and `height` are texture coordinates, and `xoffset`, `yoffset`, and `xadvance` describe where to place each character and how much to move the cursor after placing. [Full documentation here](https://www.angelcode.com/products/bmfont/documentation.html).

It works almost perfectly, however, the character spacing is too close or too far, resulting in overlapping or generally wrong placement, like this:

[image: SDF font]

As per the code:

```
private string resourceDir = "../../../Pastel/Resources/";
public Texture fontTexture;

public Vector2 fontTexScale;
public float fontLineHeight;

public Dictionary<int, Character> charactersDictionary;

public struct Character
{
    public int charId;

    public float x;
    public float y;
    public float width;
    public float height;

    public float xOffset;
    public float yOffset;
    public float xAdvance;

    public Vector3[] vertexPositions;
    public Vector2[] vertexUvs;
}

public GuiFontManager(string filePath)
{
    ParseFont(filePath);
}

public void ParseFont(string filePath)
{
    charactersDictionary = new();

    if (File.Exists(resourceDir + "Textures/Text/" + filePath))
    {
        // Read a text file line by line.
        string[] rawData = File.ReadAllLines(resourceDir + "Textures/Text/" + filePath);

        string[] firstLineSplit = rawData[1].Split(" ", StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

        // get line height
        fontLineHeight = float.Parse(firstLineSplit[1].Split("=")[1]);

        // get texture scale
        fontTexScale.X = float.Parse(firstLineSplit[3].Split("=")[1]);
        fontTexScale.Y = float.Parse(firstLineSplit[4].Split("=")[1]);

        // get character variables
        for (int i = 5; i < rawData.Length - 1; i++)
        {
            Character character = new Character();

            string[] lineSplit = rawData[i].Split(" ", StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            for (int j = 1; j < 9; j++)
            {
                string[] lineVariables = lineSplit[j].Split("=");
                switch (lineVariables[0])
                {
                    case "id":
                        character.charId = int.Parse(lineVariables[1]);
                        break;
                    case "x":
                        character.x = float.Parse(lineVariables[1]) / fontTexScale.X;
                        break;
                    case "y":
                        character.y = -float.Parse(lineVariables[1]) / fontTexScale.Y;
                        break;
                    case "width":
                        character.width = float.Parse(lineVariables[1]) / fontTexScale.X;
                        break;
                    case "height":
                        character.height = float.Parse(lineVariables[1]) / fontTexScale.Y;
                        break;
                    case "xoffset":
                        character.xOffset = float.Parse(lineVariables[1]) / fontTexScale.X;
                        break;
                    case "yoffset":
                        character.yOffset = -float.Parse(lineVariables[1]) / fontTexScale.Y;
                        break;
                    case "xadvance":
                        character.xAdvance = float.Parse(lineVariables[1]) / fontTexScale.X;
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }

            }

            float width = character.width;
            float height = character.height;

            character.vertexPositions = new Vector3[]
            {
                new Vector3(-width, height, 0f),
                new Vector3(width, height, 0f),
                new Vector3(width, -height, 0f),
                new Vector3(-width, -height, 0f)
            };

            float u = character.x;
            float v = character.y;

            character.vertexUvs = new Vector2[]
            {
                new Vector2(u, v),
                new Vector2(u + width, v),
                new Vector2(u + width, v - height),
                new Vector2(u, v - height),
            };

            charactersDictionary.Add(character.charId, character);
        }

    }
}
```

Then, when adding to the screen, I use this:

```
public override void Text(string text, GuiFontManager guiFont, float scale = 5f, bool centred = false, float maxLineLength = 1000f)
{
    char[] characters = text.ToCharArray();

    List<Vector3> vertexPositions = new();
    List<Vector2> vertexUvs = new();

    // Get character positions in line

    float xDelta = 0;

    foreach (char character in characters)
    {
        GuiFontManager.Character textCharacter = guiFont.charactersDictionary[character];

        for (int i = 0; i < textCharacter.vertexPositions.Length; i++)
        {
            vertexPositions.Add((textCharacter.vertexPositions[i] * scale) + (xDelta + (textCharacter.xOffset * scale), (textCharacter.yOffset * scale), 0f));
        }
        vertexUvs.AddRange(textCharacter.vertexUvs);

        xDelta += textCharacter.xAdvance * scale;

    }

    this.vertexPositions = vertexPositions.ToArray();
    this.vertexUvs = vertexUvs.ToArray();
}
```

I've spent a while trying to find the solution but can't figure it out. Can anyone see the problem?